# How to assign php variable in JavaScript value assign?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

**How to assign on this php variable assign javasript value**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var var_example = "2222";

</script>

<?php 
  echo $var_example_php =   ?        

  /// How to assign on this php variable asign javasript value 
?>
```

Comment: There has been 100 of questions exactly dealing with same question on SO

Comment: You commented that you want to assing PHP value to javascript, but your example shows that you are assigning javascript variable value to php

Comment: you can do it with `ob_start()` function.. check out my answer

Comment: Of course there are ways to do that, but they are not simple/elegant.

Comment: (Stupid rule the one with editing your post only 5 mins !) JS to PHP: Use hidden input in PHP, set valute in JS, submit page. Not elegant, though. But if you really need to do that... PHP to JS: it is currrently done in scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply cannot do that, you need to understand the difference between client/server side programming, you cannot assign Javascript value to PHP variable, yea but you can assign PHP value to your javascript

Comment: So there is not any other way for this about Means i have one php variable now i want php variable in javascipt value there

Comment: yes you can use php variable value in JavaScript but you cannot assign javascript variable value to a php variable

Comment: you can do that.. check out my answer

Comment: @MateiMihai It can be done scanning the whole page, he can't do it simply else

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do that. An alternative may be creating a cookie using javascript and then read the cookie in PHP.

In Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
</script>
```

And in PHP

```
<?php 
   $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];

   echo $phpVar;
?>
```

But an important point, for this to run the browser needs reload.

Best regards...

Comment: Surely this has really worked for me, I knew I could use cookies as an alternative BUT was worried of adding plugins. And this did not require that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ob_start()` function ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)). If you use this method you can call a function and parse the html content. You search for your variable and get it with php..

```
<html>
  <head>
  <?php
    $my_var = '';


    function callback($buffer)
    {
      global $my_var;
      $arr = array();

      preg_match('/var_example = \"(?P<var>\w+)\"*/', $arr, $buffer);

      $my_var = $arr['var'][0];  

      return $buffer;
    }

    ob_start("callback");

  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var var_example = "2222";

  </script>
  <?php

    ob_end_flush();

  ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

Use document.write function in javascript.

```
<?php
     $var_example_php = "<script>document.write(var_example);</script>";
     echo $var_example_php;
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: @Chirag but obvious you'll get an error...he is using echo in the variable value

Comment: Getting when i'm do echo before script this error come in :-----  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: for this example you need to remove echo statement `$var_example_php = "<script>document.write(var_example);</script>";`