# Assign a variable with the color to the background property in CSS

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to make an app where the user can change the bg color of a button and after that copy the CSS code from the `<style>` tags with changed background color into the buffer. For the color picker, I use http://jscolor.com/. I think I need to assign a variable with the color to the background property like this: `background: <?php echo $valueInput; ?>;` but I can't find the value where it's stored and doesn't know how to pass it to the variable. My code does copy the CSS but instead of some background color there is just this: `.jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput'}`.

````
 <script>

  function copyToClipboard(element) {
 var $temp = $("<input>");
 $("body").append($temp);
 $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
 document.execCommand("copy");
 $temp.remove();
}

</script> 

<button class="jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'button_cont'}" >
   Click here to pick a color
</button>
Value: <input id="valueInput" value="ed3330"> 


<?php $valueInput = ".jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput'}"; ?>

   <style type="text/css">
   #button_cont {
color: #fff !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
background: <?php echo $valueInput; ?>;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
border: none;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#button_cont:hover {
background: #434343;
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
box-shadow: 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

   </style>

<div id="button_cont" >CALL TO ACTION</div>  

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('style')">Copy CSS</button>
</div> ```
````

Comment: What do you need PHP for? Sounds like a Javascript/CSS issue

Comment: PHP and JS do not run at the same time; first, PHP runs on the server, once. The output is sent to the browser, where JS starts running. You need to break this down into parts: 1) get a style rule's CSS code 2) change a property value 3) copy the result to the clipboard

Comment: No I'm ok with Javascript too

Comment: from the document of Jscolor, you just need get value of `#valueInput` and do what you want, no need to php. if you want to change background color just set this value to body background or what element you want

Comment: ttrasn, no I can change the bg, I can't copy the css after

Comment: @EvgenySudakov do you want to copy the entire CSS with the new color added?

Comment: @Kalimah Apps Yes it's just what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using regexp replacement in javascript. I used CSS variable to make the regexp more reliable.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  let currentColor = $("#valueInput").val();
  let currentStyle = $(element).text();

  let newStyle = currentStyle.replace('--placeholder', "#"+currentColor);

  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(newStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```css
#button_cont {
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: --placeholder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#button_cont:hover {
  background: #434343;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<button class="jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'button_cont'}">
  Click here to pick a color
</button> Value: <input id="valueInput" value="ed3330">


<div id="button_cont">CALL TO ACTION</div>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('style')">Copy CSS</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but it copies so much code, I need just the code in `<style>` tags for a user could put it on his/her site, same code like in `<style>` tags only with actual bg

Comment: I think it copies the console (in stackoverflow) style as well. Try it on your own website and check.

Comment: Yes now it copies the right code only instead of color there's only `var(--btn-bg);`

Comment: Yes. This is CSS variable. It take the value from `:root{ --btn-bg: #COLOR; }`

Comment: Thanks but how to put there actual color, I need just like: `background: #64E8ED;`

Comment: You helped me a lot! Maybe you also know how to pass two values`$temp.val(newStyle).select();` and `$tempt.val(newtextStyle).select(); ` at the same time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901781/pass-both-values-to-variables-in-css

Answer (score 0):

your code here :

```
   <?php $valueInput = ".jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput'}"; ?>
```

..does exactly what you tell it to do; you've set `$valueInput` to be a **string** with value `.jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput'}`.

Later on you echo this variable inside your `<style>` tags, and since it's value is set to be `.jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput'}`, your code will actually print out that string without processing it any further.

You can check what value is set for a variable by using `var_dump($variable)`, this function will tell you what type of variable you've set and what its value is. For more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

colorpicker.js comes with some examples on its website for help you figure out how to use it, more details here: http://jscolor.com/examples/

Furthermore, you cannot pass variables from JavaScript to PHP on the same page. JavaScript is client side code, PHP is server side code. More details on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693727/11787139